# IntegrityError when saving extended Django Package

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-newsletter](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-newsletter) in a project I'm currently working on. I am required to get some extra information from subscribers so I've extended the model. However when I'm saving the form im geting the following Exception: **IntegrityError at /newsletter/
newsletter_subscription.newsletter_id may not be NULL** I would greatly appreciate assitance with the problem I am facing.

My model is constructed as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from newsletter.models import Subscription
from datetime import datetime


class Subscriber(Subscription):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lanme = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

My form:

```
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
from myapp.apps.mjnewsletter.models import Subscriber
from newsletter.forms import SubscribeRequestForm

class NewsletterSubForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        exclude = ('user',
                   'name_field',
                   'newsletter',
                   'create_date',
                   'activation_code',
                   'subscribed',
                   'subscribe_date',
                   'unsubscribed',
                   'unsubscribe_date')
        labels = {
            'fname': 'First Name',
            'lanme': 'Last Name',
            'email_field': 'Email',
            'dob': 'Date of Birth',
            'postcode': 'Post Code',
            'phone': 'Phone',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewsletterSubForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method ='post'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Subscribe'))
        self.fields.keyOrder = [
            'fname',
            'lanme',
            'email_field',
            'dob',
            'postcode',
            'phone',
        ]
```

And my view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from myapp.apps.mjnewsletter.models import Subscriber
from myapp.apps.mjnewsletter.forms import NewsletterSubForm


def subscribe(request):

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = NewsletterSubForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fname, lname, email_field, dob, postcode, phone = (form.cleaned_data['fname'],
                                                               form.cleaned_data['lanme'],
                                                               form.cleaned_data['email_field'],
                                                               form.cleaned_data['dob'],
                                                               form.cleaned_data['postcode'],
                                                               form.cleaned_data['phone'])

            subscriber = Subscriber.objects.create(fname=fname,
                                    lanme=lname,
                                    email_field=email_field,
                                    dob=dob,
                                    postcode=postcode,
                                    phone=phone)
            subscriber.save()

            messages.add_message(request, message.SUCCESS, 'Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter.')
    else:
        form = NewsletterSubForm()

    return render(request, 'mjnewsletter/subscribe.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: did you try deleting your database and then running syncdb? that's most likely what's going on...

Comment: The table in the database exists Kenvin's answer below address the issue appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're subclassing `newsletter.models.Subscription` which has a foreign key to `newsletter.models.Newsletter`. Your subclassed model has all of the fields of its parent model - if that doesn't make sense have another look at the docs on [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

This means that when you save a new `Subscriber` you have to provide all of the fields that the parent `Subscription` model requires, and one of those fields is a foreign key to `newsletter.models.Newsletter` which can't be NULL. So you'll have to supply that in your `subscribe` view.

Comment: his error is the exact opposite, he changed somehing to feature a null value, which "may not be" for some data already stored

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I'm probably just being dumb, but I don't see where he's changed newsletter_id (I assume that's the something you're talking about?) to a null value. Give me a hint?

Comment: Thanks for the the help Kevin. You were right I needed to pay closer attention to the the class i was inheriting form I sorted out various other issues that I had made uninformed assumption about.